# empty TreeView in QML from jsonModel

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qabstractitemmodel

I am trying to display a Json TreeView in QML from c++ jsonModel ([this one](https://github.com/dridk/QJsonModel)) but it's displayed empty in QML, with no data in it. while running the example in c++ it works fine.I used TreeView as QML type and setContextProperty("qjsonmodel",model) in c++ to make the connection between c++ and QML.

this is what's displayed in QML.

[image]

```
TreeView{
        id:tree
        x: 0
        //anchors.fill: parent
        width: 335
        height: 420
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 6
        anchors.rightMargin: 1287
        anchors.bottom: frame.top
        anchors.top: parent.top
        clip: true

        model: qjsonmodel
        TableViewColumn{
            title:"Defects"

        }

    }
```

Comment: One possibility is, you are using roles incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that the model has no roles, the solution is to create those roles for it you must make the following changes:

***.h**

```
...

class QJsonModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QJsonModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~QJsonModel();
    enum JsonRoles{
        KeyRole = Qt::UserRole + 1000,
        ValueRole
    };
    ...
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    ...
};
```

***.cpp**

```
...
QVariant QJsonModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    QJsonTreeItem *item = static_cast<QJsonTreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {

        if (index.column() == 0)
            return QString("%1").arg(item->key());

        if (index.column() == 1)
            return QString("%1").arg(item->value());
    }
    else if (role == KeyRole) {
        return QString("%1").arg(item->key());
    }
    else if(role == ValueRole){
        return QString("%1").arg(item->value());
    }
    return QVariant();

}
...
QHash<int, QByteArray> QJsonModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[KeyRole] = "keyData";
    roles[ValueRole] = "valueData";
    return roles;
}
...
```

*.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TreeView{
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: qjsonmodel
        TableViewColumn{
            title:"Key"
            role: "keyData"
        }
        TableViewColumn{
            title:"Role"
            role: "valueData"
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>You can find a complete example in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50007170).</sub>